# Maven not including resources folder in webapp archetype

Tags: java, maven, build, resources, webapp2

I have a simple Maven application that I build with Maven (simply clean install).

The app was generated starting from the maven webapp archetype.

When building and generating the war I want src/main/resources and all of its contents to be included in the .war, however this doesn't happen.

I use the following build in my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the maven-archetype-webapp, the pom is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-war</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>example-war Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>example-war</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I added a an image and properties file

```
$ find src/
src/
src/main
src/main/resources
src/main/resources/test.img
src/main/resources/test.properties
src/main/webapp
src/main/webapp/index.jsp
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

jar tvf target/example-war.war
     0 Thu Jan 19 15:28:18 GMT 2017 META-INF/
   134 Thu Jan 19 15:28:16 GMT 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Thu Jan 19 15:28:18 GMT 2017 WEB-INF/
     0 Thu Jan 19 15:28:18 GMT 2017 WEB-INF/classes/
    57 Thu Jan 19 15:24:40 GMT 2017 index.jsp
     0 Thu Jan 19 15:28:16 GMT 2017 WEB-INF/classes/test.img
     0 Thu Jan 19 15:28:16 GMT 2017 WEB-INF/classes/test.properties
   222 Thu Jan 19 15:24:40 GMT 2017 WEB-INF/web.xml
     0 Thu Jan 19 15:28:18 GMT 2017 META-INF/maven/
     0 Thu Jan 19 15:28:18 GMT 2017 META-INF/maven/com.greg/
     0 Thu Jan 19 15:28:18 GMT 2017 META-INF/maven/com.greg/example-war/
   875 Thu Jan 19 15:26:00 GMT 2017 META-INF/maven/com.greg/example-war/pom.xml
   116 Thu Jan 19 15:28:18 GMT 2017 META-INF/maven/com.greg/example-war/pom.properties
```